# Connecting Oracle DB from PySpark 3.1.2 - fails with Py4JJavaError

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pyspark

I am trying out PySpark3.2.1 with Oracle 11G. It fails with the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PySpark_Oracle_Connection").getOrCreate()

driver = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/dbTEST'
user = 'myname'
password = 'mypswd'
table = 'mytable'

SPARK_CLASS_PATH = "C:\Oracle_Client\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar"

df = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
    .option('driver', driver)\
    .option('url', url)\
    .option('dbtable', table)\
    .option('user',user)\
    .option('password',password).load()
```

I'd appreciate a quick help, please. I have gone through previous posts, but still doesn't work.

Comment: while submitting spark app through `spark-submit` are you passing these parameters -  `--driver-class-path C:\Oracle_Client\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar --jars C:\Oracle_Client\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar`

Comment: I am using Spyder to execute. I am not a developer. I am statistics guy, just trying PySpark  as a layman, by learning from google. How do I pass this in python code in Spyder pls?

Comment: Not sure about Spyder, but if you have spark installed and configured properly, then you will be able to run spark applications using `spark-submit` command. Have a look at this, there is an info for the python app as well - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: these as well - https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/submit-spark-application-python-example/ AND https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-submit-command/

Comment: All these links are talking about how to use Python on Spark. I need how to run PySpark package with jodbs.jar in windows10. I have not installed Spark spark separately, but my Spark is part of PySpark package in Anaconda environment - ~Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark –

Comment: Things are different here - you have pyspark module installed, which means you can write python code without getting any pyspark module specific errors in Spyder, right? However, to execute the same  written code you need a Spark environment, i.e. Spark is installed and configured properly, you can use Spark Sandbox for the same purpose

Answer (score 1):

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Error itself suggests the problem root cause i.e. `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` class was not found when spark tried to read from your oracle db table.

So now, you just have to tell the spark to find your jar. This can be done by changing `spark-defaults.conf` file which should be present in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` directory. If not present, then add it yourself with the following config:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath C:\Oracle_Client\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath C:\Oracle_Client\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar
```

Or just use the --jars option while submitting the job.

Comment: I am sorry for unable to find SPARK_HOME in my windows10. Tried various things from google search, nothing seems to work for me. I dont know anything in Java or jar. I am a statistics guy trying out PySpark. Pls let me know how do I find/set SPARK_HOME in Windows10 machine.

Comment: In Windows command prompt, try `echo %SPARK_HOME%`

Comment: When I submit "echo %SPARK_HOME%" on CMD, it returns "%SPARK_HOME%" only, nothing else. I tried to set %SPARK_HOME% in windows configuration, then PySpark itself fails. I have got a conf file at "~Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\conf.py" , but there is no way I can specify jdbc jars in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
```

is the old version with `ojdbc8.jar` you must use

```
driver= 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
```